# Can't set the label on form

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a Form with some private properties

```
namespace TestApplication
{
    public partial class ResultDialog : Form
    {
          String someText;
```

In a method, I have a method called SetupForm

```
 label1.Text = someText;
```

I get an error message and it says

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   TestApplication.ResultDialog.someText'    X:\ResultDialog.cs  50  13  TestApplication

Comment: Is `SetupForm` a static function?

Comment: show the method SetupForm. It looks like it is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the code in same file try out

```
 this.label1.Text = this.someText;
```

**Must sure that you are not setting value in static function**

Answer (score 0):

Is label1 or SetupForm static? if so your string needs to be static as well.

Static functions can only alter static values. If the function is static, it wont know what label1 is as its part of an instance of that class.

Bad:

```
class SomeClass
{
     string m_value = 0;

     static setValue(int value)
     {
          m_value = value;
     }
}
```

Good:

```
class SomeClass
{
     static string m_value = 0;

     static setValue(int value)
     {
       m_value = value;
     }
}
```

What you probably need:

```
static void SetupForm(Label label, string value)
{
    label.Text = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, your method "SetupForm" might be a static method and that might be the primary reason behind getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Is the setup form method being called before the Initialize Method in the constructor?  If so the label doesn't exist yet.